# Does browser support WebDriver or does WebDriver support browser

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

Is it the browser job to support WebDriver or is it WebDriver job to support each browser?
I mean if there is a new release of Chrome does this mean that WebDriver works right away because the support is included in the new Chrome release?

Or is WebDriver support added later by the developers of WebDriver?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run selenium webdriver in Chrome browser, we need to take the help of ChromeDriver which is a separate executable that selenium webdriver uses to control chrome. ChromeDriver is supported by the Chromium team, ChromeDriver is a standalone server which implements WebDriver's wire protocol for Chromium.

http://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-run-webdriver-in-chrome-browser

Yes, Webdriver made changes later that's the reason new jars of selenium launches so rapidly.

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: Tanks! Is there then difference in the browser support if I use Java, Ruby or JavaScript?

Comment: No, there is nothing difference in the browser support in term of language you are using. more people prefer java because it is flexible . many companies uses ruby and .Net because they already have resource those knew that languages.  Feel free to use any language.